# Automatically composing documents from multiple text files which are not LaTeX formatted?

Tags: external-files, include, automation, parsing

I'm looking for a way to create a songbook out of individual song files.

Each song file is a self-contained block of text data consisting of:

- Song name
- Song author
- Some details (optional)
- Lyrics with chords (to be typeset within a LaTeX environment `guitar`)

If I was doing this **manually** I'd put something like this in file `song1.tex`:

```
    \section{Song Name}
    \paragraph{Song author}
    \textit{Some details}
    \begin{guitar}
        Lyrics with chrods
    \end{guitar}
```

And then use `\include{song1}` in the `main.tex`.
(I have found a way to include all the files [automatically using a Lua script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560105/221376))

However, I want the source files to be formatted as minimally as possible (they are meant to be added by non-TeX savvy people).

I was considering storing the songs in plain `.txt` files, where the line number specifies the fields:

```
Song Name
Song Author
Song details
Song lyrics...
....
```

But I'm not 100% how to easily parse this. Also, something like multiline Song details breaks this.

Other ideas included storing it in JSON:

```
{"name":"Name",
"author":"Author",
"details":"Details",
"lyrics":"Song \n Lyrics"
}
```

or YAML:

```
name: Name
author: Author
details: >
  Multi-line
  Details
lyrics: >
  Multiline
  Lyrics
```

And parse those?

**What would be the most natural way to do this in LaTeX? How would you go about this?**

Comment: If you can store the data as CSV then you can use the [datatool](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) package.

Comment: There is also a [GUI](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) to prepare the data more easily.

Comment: See also https://tex-talk.net/2012/03/generating-latex-code-with-a-template-engine/ which is about songs specifically.

Comment: Or if you like C# you could try something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544942/templating-with-scriban/544976.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a song file `MHALL.txt` (Mary Had A Little Lamb), according to the OP's desired format:

```
Mary Had a Little Lamb
Anonymous
Children's song
^{A}Mary had a little lamb,
^{E}Little lamb, ^{A}little lamb,
^{A}Mary had a little lamb,
Its ^{E}fleece was white as ^{A}snow.

^{A}Everywhere that Mary went,
^{E}Mary went, ^{A}Mary went,
^{A}Everywhere that Mary went
The ^{E}lamb was sure to ^{A}go
 
It ^{A$\sharp$}followed her to school one day
...
```

and the following short code using `readarray`, the output may be formatted as an annotated song lyric.  I don't know anything about a `guitar` environment, so I created my own format for "formatting" chords, namely, to top-lap the chord name, using the input syntax `^{<chord name>}` as an active input from the input file. Note that chord names like `^{A$\flat$}` are perfectly suitable to this input style. Obviously, this part of the formatting can be tailored to the OP's desires.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,forloop,stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{.9\baselineskip}% VERTICAL CHORD POSITION
\newcounter{songlines}
{\catcode`\^=\active 
  \gdef^#1{\trlap{\fbox{\tiny\sffamily\bfseries#1}}}}% CHORD FORMAT
\newcommand\formatsong[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \catcode`\^=\active 
  \readrecordarray{#1}\songdata
  \section{\songdata[1]}%
  \paragraph{\songdata[2]}%
  \textit{\songdata[3]}%
  \begin{quote}
  \forloop{songlines}{4}{\value{songlines}<\nrecords}{%
    \songdata[\thesonglines]\\
  }%
  \end{quote}
  \egroup
}
\fboxsep=2pt
\begin{document}
\formatsong{MHALL.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

Just to show how the chord format can be adjusted to suit, I grab some routines from my answer at [Typesetting guitar chord diagrams in a songbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324828/typesetting-guitar-chord-diagrams-in-a-songbook/324924#324924) and to my prior code, I merely enlarge the VERTICAL CHORD POSITION (to allow room for the chord typesetting) and simplify the CHORD FORMAT (removing all extraneous formatting).

Then, using the pulled-in routines to define for the user guitar chords like `\Cm` (C-minor) and `\GM` (G-major), I can allow the user to specify these as the chords in the input file:

```
Mary Had a Little Lamb
Anonymous
Children's song
^{\Cm}Mary had a little lamb,
^{\GM}Little lamb, ^{\Cm}little lamb,
...
```

Then, with this augmented code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,forloop,stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{2.7\baselineskip}% VERTICAL CHORD POSITION
\newcounter{songlines}
{\catcode`\^=\active 
  \gdef^#1{\trlap{#1}}}% CHORD FORMAT
\newcommand\formatsong[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \catcode`\^=\active 
  \readrecordarray{#1}\songdata
  \section{\songdata[1]}%
  \paragraph{\songdata[2]}%
  \textit{\songdata[3]}%
  \begin{quote}
  \forloop{songlines}{4}{\value{songlines}<\nrecords}{%
    \songdata[\thesonglines]\\
  }%
  \end{quote}
  \egroup
}
\fboxsep=2pt
% FOLLOWING PULLED FROM ANSWER AT
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324828/typesetting-guitar-chord-diagrams-in-a-songbook/324924#324924
\usepackage{musixguit}
\def\chordalign{\dimexpr2.2ex}% 2.2ex sets alignment of chord
\def\chordminwidth{\dimexpr6.5ex}% 6.5ex provides min. hskip for optional argument
\newcommand\guitarchord[2]{%
  \savestack#1{\kern\chordalign\NOtes\guitar #2\en}
}
\newcommand\showchord[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\tmpuaw{T}\else\def\tmpuaw{F}\fi%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{#1}{%
    \makebox[0ex][l]{#2}\kern\chordminwidth}{O}{l}{F}{\tmpuaw}{L}%
}
\newcommand\chordline[2]{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\chordminwidth\showchord{#1}#2\else\showchord[#2]{#1}\fi%
}
\raiseguitar {0}

\guitarchord\Cm{{Cm $^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52}
\guitarchord\GM{G{}o-----\gbarre3\gdot25\gdot35\gdot44}
%
\begin{document}
\formatsong{MHALL.txt}
\end{document}
```

the result may be more what the OP had in mind:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the basic conceptual idea I'd use 1) simple sources, as you mention, and b) generate those .tex files e.g. by some scripting language (which is a no- or low-brainer for the experienced scripter).

### Examples for simple sources

- pure ASCII, e.g. with a suitable and simple directory structure
- a database, like MS Access (or mysql or whatever)
- a web-formular
  etc.

### Scripting e.g. by

- Perl
- php (command line)
- Javascript
- concatenation by dedicated query in MS Access (or mysql or whatever)

Let me know your preference and I'll try to work out some basic code for you (if I can).

### Structures

#### One file only approach

Use dedicated (own) markup, which your script can easily identify. Example, easy to do in Perl:

```
#N Blowin' in the wind
#A Bob Dylon
#D This song was ... bla bla
(many lines later
and this is all you should know about it
#I Guitar
#L How man roads
must a man walk down
...
```

#### Directory coded

Let's say there are more songs than authors. So a structure could be like this

```
\Bob Dylan
\Bob Dylan\Blowin in the wind
\Bob Dylan\Blowin in the wind\details.txt
\Bob Dylan\Blowin in the wind\lyrics.txt
\Bob Dylan\Blowin in the wind\instruments.txt
```

Splitting the PATH at "\" gives you all the nitty gritty details and access.

#### Database approach

You may want to define fields in a DB, or columns in a spreadsheet like Excel, like so:

```
author song details instrument lyrics year ...
```

where details and lyrics allow for long texts, while the others may be shorter. E.g. in MS Access you can alway turn the the table into a form, like so:

TABLE-STRUCTURE

How the data sets could look like:
[image: How the data sets could look like]

When you start filling it:
[image: When you start filling it]

FORM

What your people might use for entry
[image: What your people might use for entry]

BTW ... you'll have the same ingredients and representation when doing this via a web-interface (form) with an underlying database (like mysql).

P.S.: Let me add from a different post here, that using `datatool` would open up this opportunity for you from a system design point of view:

- use some frontend for your writers to enter information (DB, web-form)
- access each dataset via https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool in Latex